# LXD/LXC: Difference between disk device and lxc.mount.entry

Tags: mount, lxc

I've been using the following to share a folder from my LCX host into a container:

```
lxc config device add containerxyz directoryname disk source=/storage/containerxyz path=/mnt/storage/
```

This works perfectly fine, I can have the container read and write files to the `/storage/containerxyz` path in the host, however [I see online some people suggesting](https://gist.github.com/julianlam/07abef272136ea14a627) do to this instead:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /storage/containerxyz /var/lib/lxc/containerxyz/rootfs/mnt/storage/ none bind 0 0
```

Whats the practical difference between those two ways to having host directory available to the container and drawbacks of each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some clarifications first: Both LXC and LXD are tools to manage Linux containers. LXC is low level, LXD is a newer, more polished containers manager.

So, `lxc config` is LXD's way to configure a Linux container, while `lxc.mount.entry =` inside container's config file is LXC's lower level way to achieve the same thing.

Apparently you use LXD, so stick with it, there's nothing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!